# Laravel response()->json returns html page on server in case of validation errors

Tags: laravel, api, apache, validation, jsonresponse

I have a Laravel 8 API application. Below is my example test method in the controller which return status 422 with invalid data JSON response.

```php
public function testInvalid()
    {
        $arrResponse = [
            'success'    => false,
            'message'    => 'message',
            'data'       => [],
            'errors'     => ['error'],
            'error_code' => 422,
        ];

        return response()->json($arrResponse, 422);
    }
```

the above should return the JSON response in postman:

```json
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "message",
    "data": [],
    "errors": [
        "error"
    ],
    "error_code": 422
}
```

But it only works on the `local` machine.

When I run same on the `server` it returns the `Unprocessable entity` HTML page.

But if I update it to `200 OK` response code with the same response format. then it returns JSON response from the `server` too.

```php
        return response()->json($arrResponse, 200);
```

all other valid request works fine and returns JSON response from the `server`.

> Is it something I need to check on Apache web-server configuration?

**Note: I tried passing `Accept: application/json` and `Content-Type: application/json` headers in postman request. still the same.**

Comment: Turn on Debug mode and Check the error logs

Comment: The debug mode in laravel is ON on the server too. no logs in the laravel logs. As it not considered Exception. 422 is validation error (means valid response) but just not returning json, instead default HTML page.

Comment: Can you verify that the response is really coming from Laravel and not from the web server? Like post a screenshot of the page or the HTML. I could imagine that the web server returns its own HTML instead of the real framework response.

Comment: @Kevin yes the response page is of web server according to the error code generated by json response. if I set it to 404 then the default html not found page is thrown. and if 422 then the associated html page for it. so only the json body is missing. but the error codes are correctly thrown back to response.

Comment: This is not a laravel issue.

Comment: @marius-ciclistu yes I suspect too; may be apache issue. but if you know the best answer where and how to fix then please let me know.

Comment: It could also be a custom middleware that throws exception on non 200 status codes in laravel. If it is not this case, then you should search a way to overwrite the php response for non 200 status codes and then do the opposite (server side). Also have a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors#ignoring-exceptions-by-type

Comment: @marius-ciclistu that middleware should also act same on the local. but let me clear again that there is no such middleware in my case. it's very straight route.

Comment: Then the issue is from the load balancer or ngnx/apache.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to the `Accept` header of your request.

If not provided, Laravel defaults to `Accept: text/html` and error handling will provide you with a response matching your accept header.

By providing `Accept: application/json` with your request headers, Laravel will return the error response as JSON as well.

Comment: Already mentioned in `Note` at very last in my question. already tried everything.